# How to send SMS with confirmation code using Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have two groups of people in my app - managers and employees. Managers have the ability to register their employees. Basically they fill a form for them (**Phone number**, Full name, date of birth and so on). All of the information is in kept in the `employees` collection in the Cloud firebase.

The employees can't register the app, they can only "verify their phone number". If their phone number was registered in the system, then they should get an SMS with a confirmation code. As you can see, I currently, kept the employees information in the database and not in the authenation section (as I did for managers who sign in with email and password).

The ideas is as follows:

1. Manager should register the volunteer's phone number (as I understand to the Authentication section).
2. Employee installs the app and in the login section, enters their phone number. Another sms should be sent to them with the confirmation code which the employee should fill.

So I have two questions:

1. How should I add the employee beside adding them in the firebase cloud?
2. When employee is trying to sign in with the phone number, how can I check if he already in the system and if not, print a toast or something?
3. A harder question would be how should I send the SMS confirmation code?

Also I want to mention that I don't use FirebaseUI (we have a custom view of the login).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, Use this code for send otp:

```
private String verificationCode = "";
        
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallback;

sendOtp();
varifyMobile();


private void sendOtp() {
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCallback = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationActivity.this, "OTP Sent failed, Please click on Resend OTP.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            pd.dismiss();
            verificationCode = s;
            Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationActivity.this, "OTP has been sent on " + mobile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}

private void varifyMobile() {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+91" + mobile,                     // Phone number to verify
            2,                           // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.MINUTES,                // Unit of timeout
            OtpVerificationActivity.this,        // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallback);
}
```

For Verify Otp:

```
String otp = edtOtp.getText().toString();
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCode, otp);
                    SigninWithPhone(credential);

private void SigninWithPhone(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationActivity.this, "Otp verification complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(OtpVerificationActivity.this, "Error: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit where the code goes? I guess that `sendOtp` should be executed when the manager done filling the form and the `varifyMobile` should be executed when the employee clicked "verify number"? Also what `sendOtp` sends?

Comment: these both methods you have to call when you want send otp

Comment: Ok thanks, so the first code is n the manager's screen and the second code is in employee screen, right? Can you explain what `sendOtp` does? Does it send an SMS to the employee? Because it should not.

Comment: send otp setting the callback details and verifyMobile is sending the otp

Comment: I tried it now. It sends a verification code when the manager registers the employee. As I mentioned, I want the verification code to be send only when the employee will try to login himself. How can I register a user without sending him a verification code?

Comment: actually you can not register with mobile number without verification.

Comment: you can register a user with email without verfication.